# Is it possible to convert html homepage to a react component to render in Index.js Create-React-App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an existing templated website that i want to continue with react. I decided to use create-react-app for that, but i do not know how to move the html based template to the react application. What i am trying to do now is to find a way to create a functional component out of the html file and then pass it to the index.js file for rendering. What i don't know is if this will work. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! A React component is almost always a kind of template (unless it returns null). If you have tried some things, or read some documentation, already, then let us know what you have tried or read. You can include code snippets and links in your question post, and that's what we would need to see to spot any errors you are making and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have tiny changes with HTML and JSX. JSX use className instead of class and htmlFor instead of for as mentioned up there.
If you are using VS code editor, here are your steps to make things a bit easier:-

1. In Vs code, Download an extension name HTML to JSX.
2. open your raw HTML code with VS code.
3. Select all code you want to convert.
4. Right-click and see at the bottom of the list, you will see an option Convert HTML to JSX. Click it and you are done.

[step:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Ye9.png)

[step:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3N6Q.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urZWt.png)

Comment: Wow this is great. I do not know VS code has an extension like that.

Comment: If you like it you can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and JSX was designed to be very similar to HTML to allow just that sort of thing.

However, JSX does have a [few differences from HTML](https://gist.github.com/MonaTem/5821a5cb5ec6623d91819bb86b7e58e5), which you'll want to read about.  For instance, certain HTML attributes "overlap" with JS keywords, so in JSX you should use (for instance) `htmlFor` instead of `for`, and `className` instead of `class`.  Also every tag has to be closed (as in XHTML).

Once you get your initial HTML into your Javascript file, you'll then want to start breaking up the parts of that page into separate React *components*, so that you can focus on them (and their logic) in independent chunks.

Comment: Oh okay. So i can just change the syntax of the html file to look like a 'jsx' file, and then make i a component and then export and render in the index.js file. Assuming the function is homepage, then '''<homepage/>''' will be rendered. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Yup ... but of course the ultimate reason to do all that isn't just to have "HTML in JSX format" ... it's to augment that HTML/JSX with Javascript :)  Good luck (and don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your question).